# Microsoft Access 2010 on Windows 7 64-bit, and MSCOMM32.ocx

Tags: vba, x86-64, ms-access-2010, mscomm32

Over the weekend, I had a hard drive failure on my business' POS & database computer. We have an Orbit Metrologic scanner hooked up to it via USB, and it's emulated for comm port COM3. The scanner works, and I was able to restore our database completely, except that our scanner is not able to communicate with Access 2010. Before we ran the 32-bit version of access, however this time I've downloaded the 64-bit version of access, seeing as we have a 64-bit machine.

Things I have done:

- Registered MSCOMM32.ocx with Regsvr32 in SysWOW64 (the same one from the failed hard drive, I was able to boot to a linux live CD and extract it)
- Disabled the MSCOMM32.ocx Windows 7 Kill-Bit using [ADM.exe](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/acm.html)
- Enabled all ActiveX controls to run without question in the trust center
- Registered MSCOMM32.ocx in the VBA References

Can MSCOMM32.ocx work in a 64-bit enviornment? Or will I have to revert to 32-bit access?

Comment: Absolutely no idea whether this will help or not: http://www.sevenforums.com/drivers/47248-mscomm32-2.html

Comment: No :/ I already saw that form a while ago when Googling it. Thanks for the help though Remou.

Comment: Stupid Question, but in doing registrations i have noticed that there are two forms of Regsvr, 32-bit and 64-bit.  From what i have read in the past, 64-bit sends ocx files to thw SysWOW64 'ad-hoc' folder, and the 32-bit sends it to the System/<something> folder.  Cant remember if there is a command line directive to shift the registration from 32 to 64.  Which operation have you performed?

Comment: I copied my OCX to SysWOW64 and registered it by typing `C:`, `CD Windows/SysWOW64`, and `Regsvr32 MSCOMM32.OCX` into the command line.

Comment: ...And from [what I'm reading](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sbappdev/thread/91cf3127-70fe-4726-8a27-31b8964430c5/), that's the proper way to register a 64-bit control. So I guess that's options out too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this particular problem was solved by uninstalling the 64-bit version of Microsoft Access and re-installing the 32-bit version. The control was recognized right away.